# TFS CAL with Multiple On Premise Instances

Tags: tfs

We're in the middle of migrating code, builds etc from an old TFS 2015 instance to a new TFS 2017 instance. So currently we have 2 TFS on premise instances. The migration is likely to take 6 - 12 months due to time constraints on resources.

One question we haven't been able to find a clear answer to is how the CAL licensing would work in this situation. We have users with MSDN licenses which gives a TFS CAL and also users with Test Pro licenses which also provides a CAL. But do those CAL's cover the user using both instances during the 6 - 12 months while we complete the migration?

Answer (score 1):

> To license TFS 2015/2017, you’ll need a **TFS server license** and a
>   Windows operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each
>   machine running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person
>   connecting to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for
>   people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access,
>   which is free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as Test Manager, Package Management, and
>   Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions
>   are included with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions and many
>   others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no
>   Visual Studio subscription is required.

In your case, for every MSDN subscription that you own, you also have a TFS server licenses. So, theoretically, you could install as many TFS servers as you have MSDN subscriptions.  I am not a licensing expert, but according to TFS Licensing Whitepaper appears to say nothing about tying a user CAL to a particular TFS server installation.

You could take a look at *Daniel - the real one's* question and *Brian Harry MS*'s reply in this thread-- [Included CALs and Tiered Pricing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/07/27/included-cals-and-tiered-pricing/)  which has a similar situation like you.

Besides, If you want to double confirm this and  know more information about TFS license, you could call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. Worldwide customers can use the Guide to Worldwide Microsoft Licensing Sites to find contact information in their locations: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/